# The ComboBox does not display the specified values

Tags: excel, vba

A ComboBox is placed on a UserForm and the user must select one of the pre-specified values from the list.
No values are displayed in the ComboBox.

What's wrong with the code?

```
Sub Status()
    Dim ComboBox1 As ComboBox
    Dim valgtData As String

    ' Definerer ComboBox1 som en ComboBox på aktivt ark
    Set ComboBox1 = UserForm1.ComboBox1

    ' Indlæser data i ComboBox1
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Forbruger"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Erhverv"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Offentlig"

    ' Tjekker om der er noget valgt i ComboBox1
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        ' Henter den valgte data fra ComboBox1
        valgtData = ComboBox1.Value

        ' Indsætter den valgte data i celle A1 på arket
        ActiveSheet.Range("A20").Value = valgtData
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you see the added items **if press the combo right little arrow**?  Your code only adds items, but it does not 'select' any of them as the combo value.

Comment: No, I do not. and I thought that the ComBox1.AddItem would do the trick.

Comment: Do you receive any error on run the code? `ComBox1.AddItem` should do the job... Theoretically, a combo on a user form should be declared `As msforms.ComboBox`. `As ComboBox` means a sheet form Combo. Even if normally, VBA should know what is it about and convert it in what's necessary.

Comment: No, I don't get any error messages. The form runs perfectly, just no values are displayed in the dropdown list.

I have tried to insert ComboBox1.AddItem "value 1" in Sub UserForm_Initialize().
This gives this error: "Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value."

Comment: Then are you sure that the form keeping the combo is `UserForm1`?

Comment: Now it is, earlyer it was UserForm. The form run, but no data in the ComboBox1.

Comment: Did you try changing  the `ComboBox` variable declaration as I suggested in my second comment?

Comment: @FaneDuru
I started all over and it all worked fine.
However, I didn't find out what the problem was originally.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Status` Sub is in the code-behind of `UserForm1` and you have added a `ComboBox1` to it then you do not need the `Dim ComboBox1 As ComboBox` and `Set ComboBox1 = UserForm1.ComboBox1` lines ... you can access `ComboBox1` directly (i.e. as you then do, having removed those 2 lines, in the later `ComboBox1.AddItem  ...` lines).

If, however, the `Status` Sub is in a Module that you use to subsequently show the 'default instance' of `UserForm1` (eg using `UserForm1.Show`) then you must call `Status` before the `UserForm1.Show` line.